# How to use a specific interface on a C# object in IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have a C# class that implements 2 IEnumerable interfaces. How can I access either interface from IronPython?

My class:

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<TypeA>, IEnumerable<TypeB>
{
    IEnumerator<TypeA> IEnumerable<TypeA>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _lstTypeA.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<TypeB> IEnumerable<TypeB>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _lstTypeB.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I tried the following in Python, but although it runs without errors it does not return any elements from the IEnumerable interface:

```
x = MyClass()
xA = clr.Convert(x, IEnumerable[TypeA])
for y in xA: print y
```

Comment: What a badly designed class... Try to convince the author that he should fix it.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I am the author. Please explain why this is badly designed, so I can improve it.

Comment: I guess he meant that it's not a good design when a class implements two different `IEnumerable<T>`, because to get the implicitly-implemented `GetEnumerator()` you need a cast (and BTW it's not clear why a class represents a collection of 2 different elements...). It's probably better to expose one of the two `IEnumerable<T>`s (the less important, or both, it depends...) as a property of that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call methods and properties as you were using reflection (that is actually what it happens under the hood).

In your case you should do:

```
x = MyClass()
enumerator = IEnumerable[TypeA].GetEnumerator(x)
```

then you can loop over `enumerator`:

```
for y in enumerator:
   print y
```

Comment: Obvious once you see it... Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 5):

I don't like your class design. In particular that you implement two different versions of `IEnumerable<T>` that return different members. Two versions that return the same members is slightly better, but I still don't like that much.

1. Implementing `IEnumerable` so it's consistent with both `IEnumerable<T>`s isn't possible here. In particular that breaks the `OfType` and `Cast` linq methods.
2. You get overload resolution problems almost everywhere.  Methods like `Select<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ...)` don't know which `IEnumerable` to take.
3. You can't use `foreach` on `MyClass`
4. If both `TypeA` and `TypeB` are reference types the variance of `IEnumerable<out T>` comes back to bite you. Since both of them offer `IEnumerable<T'>` for all their common ancestors.
5. It doesn't interact well with dynamically types languages
6. A class being a two different collections at the same time rarely makes sense. It usually indicates that something went wrong in the mapping from concepts to classes.
7. It's confusing and hard to understand. My intuition tells me it's evil and that I should burn it with fire :P

And Probably several more issues I didn't think of yet.

---

The work around is simple and clean: Have two separate enumerable properties.

```
public class MyClass
{
  public IEnumerable<TypeA> TypeAs{get{_lstTypeA.Select(x=>x)}};
  public IEnumerable<TypeB> TypeBs{get{_lstTypeB.Select(x=>x)}};
}
```

Comment: Ok, I see why MyClass can be considered evil. Your suggestion to use two enumerable properties is a welcome improvement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

how i use specified interface

```
clr.AddReference('Platform.CardHost')
from Platform import CardHost
from Platform.CardHost import ICardHost

host = CardHost.CardHost.CreateInstance('session')
# ICardHost is interface
# inside C# 
# public interface ICardHost {
# IExtensionManager ExtensionManager { get; }
em = ICardHost.ExtensionManager.__get__(host)
```